# Manage images manually

Tags: media, nodes

For our new Drupal site, it would be ideal if we could manage all images manually. We need to able to resize/crop and put the files where an author decides to put them. The reason is that these images are used in multiple locations, e.g. a podcast and as thumbnail images for the corresponding video. Another reason is that these images are served from a subdomain, which is connected to a CDN (through CloudFlare).

Basically what I/we need is a URL field where an author can paste the image URL, that is then turned into an image on the website. The author would generate the various image types, e.g. thumbnail, medium, large.

I could not figure out what the best approach is to add an image/text field to a content type in order to display the image on the website. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option for remote images is the [Filefield Sources module](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources), however this will not provide the ability to manually create the thumbnail, medium, large, etc versions.

You can achieve auto-creation with image-styles and preset the dimensions or criteria that you would like for the "cropped/smaller" versions.

Lastly, if you want manual creation of those files you would have to create a new field for each version and have them pre-cropped/sized, and paste in the url from the CDN.

Comment: Thanks jsheffers, having everything done manual is the most preferable solution in our case.

Comment: Just had time to check out FileField Source. It, unfortunately, offers no option to *not* transfer the images to the local Drupal installation. When a URL is specified in, say, an article, Drupal goes ahead, downloads the image and processes it as if it were uploaded through the form. I will take a look at your third suggestion now. Thanks again.

Comment: You might also look at this module in relation to CDN: http://drupal.org/project/cdn